# Is it possible to tell from CMD whether i have Cygwin or MSYS?

Tags: cmd.exe, cygwin, mingw, msys, msys2

Is there a way that I can check, from a CMD whether a PC has Cygwin or MSYS (MSYS2, MINGW, MINGW-64...) installed?

Note that I need to be able to differentiate Cygwin from MSYS.

Thanks!

Comment: Run `uname -a` in cygwin or msys2 terminal emulator aka. mintty.

Comment: There is an environmental variable called OSTYPE, but I don't know if it is set only when they are running.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to search for some **specific files** installed by Cygwin/MSYS with the `where` command and **inspect the output folders**: for instance, you could search in cmd for these files

- msys2.exe, mingw64.exe, mingw32.exe, Cygwin.bat

In my case,

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18362.418]
(c) 2019 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users> where msys2
C:\msys64\msys2.exe

C:\Users> where mingw64
C:\msys64\mingw64.exe

C:\Users> where mingw32
C:\msys64\mingw32.exe

C:\Users> where cygwin
C:\tools\cygwin\Cygwin.bat
```

But beware, maybe some users have **just some files** with those names and **not the entire installation files**(i.e., maybe someone has `C:\msys64\msys2.exe` but there's nothing else inside `C:\msys64`): that's why I told you to **inspect the output folders**.

Try to identify some **important files that should absolutely exist** after the Cygwin/MSYS installation and search for them so that you can be mostly sure about the installation(create a batch file to automatically identify all the needed files).